# What makes Lord Buddha worthy of worshiping as to suttas?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, suttas

I know Lord Buddha is worthy of every respect but what is the correct answer/what has the Lord Buddha himself has said?

What makes a lord Buddha worthy of worship as to lord Buddha are there any reference from suttas that we can find?

Answer (score 3):

In [MN 77](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn77), the Buddha teaches a group of wanderers the five reasons why His disciples venerate Him and look to him for guidance:
1. Supreme aggregate of virtue
2. Excellent knowledge and vision
3. Supreme aggregate of wisdom
4. Teach the Four Noble Truths
5. Show the way to develop wholesome states.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Dhajagga Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn11/sn11.003.piya.html):

> I also say unto you O monks — if any fear, terror or hair standing on
>   end should arise in you when you have gone to the forest or to the
>   foot of a tree, or to an empty house (lonely place), then think only
>   of me thus:
>
> "'Such Indeed is the Blessed One, arahant (Consummate One), supremely
>   enlightened, endowed with knowledge and virtue, welcome being, knower
>   of worlds, the peerless trainer of persons, teacher of gods and men,
>   the Buddha, the Blessed One.' Monks, if you think of me, any fear,
>   terror, or standing of hair on end, that may arise in you, will pass
>   away.

And [another translation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn11/sn11.003.than.html) of the same sutta:

> "But I tell you this: If — when you have gone into the wilderness, to
>   the shade of a tree, or to an empty building — there should arise
>   fear, terror, or horripilation, then on that occasion you should
>   recollect me: 'Indeed, the Blessed One is worthy & rightly
>   self-awakened, consummate in knowledge & conduct, well-gone, an expert
>   with regard to the world, unexcelled as a trainer for those people fit
>   to be tamed, the Teacher of divine & human beings, awakened, blessed.'
>   For when you have recollected me, whatever fear, terror, or
>   horripilation there is will be abandoned.